# sentiment analysis-LSTM and word2vec models on tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, sentiment-analysis, word2vec, tensorboard

I am working now on a project including sentiment analysis on sentences. 
I got the help of this tutorial :
https://github.com/rvinas/sentiment_analysis_tensorflow

in this model, I am using CSV file containing tweets sentences which are labeled as positive or negative.
I have few questions :

1.is there a difference if I am using a word2vec algorithm like the 'skip-gram' model, and then fed the embedding layer to this network? or it is the same as initialized a random matrix and let the network to learn the words during training by itself?

2.how can I improve the model if I am using a large dataset? let's say I am using 100,000 samples .. what are the hidden-layer/batch/training-steps parameters which can give the best performance?I know there isn't a basic rule, but I would like to know if there is some certain limitation I have to consider.

3.how can I plot the positive/negative classification results with Tensorflow projector? I created a 'metadata.tsv' which consists of the words in my lexicon, but I would like to have the possibility to color the positive and negative classification

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer point 3. But point 1 , yes there is a lot of difference, and I would advise you to pass embedding vectors as the network gets to learn hyperparameters in semantic context. Point 2 advise you to look at existing research on Google scholar by searching for word2vec and lstm. I am sure there is research done in this context.

Comment: I am having a difficulty on another issue about this model. when I am training the model..everything works fine I guess..and when I am running the test samples with some batch size it also makes a good prediction. but if I want to use the model after I trained it .. with short sentences how can i do that?

Comment: I am using the same prediction operation from the graph like I used for the test samples, but with a tensor of shape 1x(max seq length) ..the problem is that it always gives me a negative result.